# Speed on an Inclined Plane in Limit as Theta goes to 0

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction

In the classic problem of a block sliding down an inclined plane (at $\theta$ with respect to the horizontal) with friction (coefficient $\mu$), the method of work and energy quickly lets us find that the speed $v$ of the block after sliding some distance $d$ down the ramp (after starting from rest) is given by

$$v=\sqrt{2gd(sin\theta-\mu cos\theta)}$$

I'm curious about the physical meaning of the result when $\theta$ goes to $0$ (degrees) - this question is asked of the reader in Taylor's *Classical Mechanics*. In the limit as $\theta$ goes to $90$, we get free-fall as expected. When $\theta$ goes to $0$ we get

$$v=\sqrt{-\mu2gd}$$

which gives an imaginary number. Is there any physical meaning behind this result, or does it simply tell us that the block will never move (the real part of its speed is 0 for all $d$). Or, far more outlandishly, is this telling us something about the magical case of a $\mu<0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be no friction force if the angle is zero. That is because there will be no force acting on the block parallel to the surface for friction to oppose if the angle between the surface and the horizontal is zero.

In any case, before the angle reaches zero, the friction force will fall below the maximum possible static friction force and motion will stop for any coefficient of friction greater than zero. The relationship between the angle and the coefficient of static friction for *impending* motion is

$μ_{s}$ = tan θ

As an example, looking at data on the Engineering tool box web site the lowest coefficient of static friction I could find was 0.05 for "lubricated and greasy diamond". That corresponds to an angle of 2.8 degrees in the above equation. At that angle, the block will stop sliding ($v=0$) due to static friction. Mathematically, putting this angle into the part of your first equation that is (sin θ - μ cos θ), yields a number greater than zero. So the end result will not be an imaginary number.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In your second paragraph, do you mean that the gravitational force (parallel to the ramp) will fall below the maximum possible static friction force?

Comment: That's exactly what I mean.